Problem converging to Pareto optimal front of DLTZ1 with NSGA-II implementation
I'm trying to implement the NSGA-II to solve multi objective optimization problems, I think my implementation is correct but it is very unstable, DLTZ1 is supposed to be not that hard to solve but if I use the standard g(x) function it converges as expected about 1 out of every 10 tries, it does fine if I manually set g(x) to 0.5. For more basic functions like the ones proposed in the paper the algorithm was first published I'm getting the expected results.
Expected solution:
Image showing the 3d plot of the expected set of solutions
Solution im getting:
Image showing the 3d plot of the solutions im getting
Its getting there but definitely not correct.
Edit: raising the population to about 300 seems to fix the convergence issues but the literature recommends the parameters set in the code.
DLTZ1:
Formulation of DLTZ1
My code:(its ready to run as is)
#Implmentation of NSGA-II algorithm with Object Oriented Programming

import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Class to represent the individual
class Individual:
    def __init__(self, values, objectives):
        # Ensure values are stored as a NumPy array
        self.values = np.array(values)
        self.objectives = objectives
        self.dominated = 0
        self.dominating = []
        self.rank = 0
        self.crowding_distance = 0.0
        self.objective_values = self.objective_function(self.values) 

    def objective_function(self, values):
        # Apply each objective function on the values array
        return np.array([objective(values) for objective in self.objectives])
    
    def recalculate_objective_values(self):
        self.objective_values = self.objective_function(self.values)
  
#Class to represent the NSGA-II algorithm
class NSGAII:
    def __init__(self, population_size, generations, mutation_rate, crossover_rate, objectives, bounds, tournament_size, dimensions):
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.population_size = population_size
        self.generations = generations
        self.mutation_rate = mutation_rate
        self.crossover_rate = crossover_rate
        self.bounds = bounds
        self.tournament_size = tournament_size
        self.population = []
        self.offspring_population = []
        self.objectives = objectives
        self.fronts = []
        self.current_generation = 0
        self.initialize_population()
    
    #Function to initialize the population
    def initialize_population(self):
        for i in range(self.population_size):
            values = np.random.uniform(low=[b[0] for b in self.bounds], high=[b[1] for b in self.bounds], size=self.dimensions)
            new_individual = Individual(values, self.objectives)
            self.population.append(new_individual)
      
    #Function to perform the tournament selection
    def tournament_selection(self):
        selected = []
        for i in range(self.tournament_size):
            selected.append(random.choice(self.population))
        best = selected[0]
        for individual in selected:
            if individual.rank < best.rank:
                best = individual
            elif individual.rank == best.rank:
                if individual.crowding_distance > best.crowding_distance:
                    best = individual
        return best
    
    #Function to perform the Simulated Binary Crossover
    def crossover(self, parent1, parent2):
        rand_mask = np.random.rand(len(parent1.values)) < self.crossover_rate
        u = np.random.rand(len(parent1.values))
        eta_c = 15  # Crossover index
        beta = np.where(u < 0.5, (2 * u)**(1 / (1 + eta_c)), (1 / (2 * (1 - u)))**(1 / (1 + eta_c)))

        child1_values = 0.5 * (parent1.values + parent2.values - beta * abs(parent2.values - parent1.values))
        child2_values = 0.5 * (parent1.values + parent2.values + beta * abs(parent2.values - parent1.values))
        
        child1_values = np.where(rand_mask, child1_values, parent1.values)
        child2_values = np.where(rand_mask, child2_values, parent2.values)

        child1_values = np.clip(child1_values, [b[0] for b in self.bounds], [b[1] for b in self.bounds])
        child2_values = np.clip(child2_values, [b[0] for b in self.bounds], [b[1] for b in self.bounds])

        return Individual(child1_values, self.objectives), Individual(child2_values, self.objectives)

    #Function to perform the mutation (poly-nomial mutation)
    def mutation(self, individual):
        mutation_mask = np.random.rand(len(individual.values)) < self.mutation_rate
        u = np.random.rand(len(individual.values))
        
        # Element-wise calculation of delta
        delta = np.minimum(individual.values - np.array([b[0] for b in self.bounds]),
                        np.array([b[1] for b in self.bounds]) - individual.values) / np.array([b[1] - b[0] for b in self.bounds])
        
        eta_m = 20  # Polynomial mutation index
        delta1 = (2 * u + (1 - 2 * u) * (1 - delta)**(eta_m + 1))**(1 / (eta_m + 1)) - 1
        delta2 = 1 - (2 * (1 - u) + 2 * (u - 0.5) * (1 - delta)**(eta_m + 1))**(1 / (eta_m + 1))
        
        deltaq = np.where(u < 0.5, delta1, delta2)
        deltamax = np.array([b[1] - b[0] for b in self.bounds])
        new_values = individual.values + mutation_mask * deltaq * deltamax  # Apply mutation mask here
        
        # Clipping the values to ensure they remain within bounds
        new_values = np.clip(new_values, [b[0] for b in self.bounds], [b[1] for b in self.bounds])
        
        # Apply the new values if mutation occurred
        if np.any(mutation_mask):
            individual.values = new_values
            individual.recalculate_objective_values()



    # Function to check if one individual dominates another
    def dominates(self, individual1, individual2):
        # Check if individual1 dominates individual2
        return all(individual1.objective_values <= individual2.objective_values) and any(individual1.objective_values < individual2.objective_values)

    #Function to perform the non-dominated sorting
    def non_dominated_sorting(self):
        fronts = []
        front = []
        for individual in self.population:
            individual.dominated = 0
            individual.dominating = []
            for other_individual in self.population:
                if self.dominates(individual, other_individual):
                    individual.dominating.append(other_individual)
                elif self.dominates(other_individual, individual):
                    individual.dominated += 1
            if individual.dominated == 0:
                individual.rank = 0
                front.append(individual)
        fronts.append(front)
        i = 0
        while len(fronts[i]) > 0:
            next_front = []
            for individual in fronts[i]:
                for other_individual in individual.dominating:
                    other_individual.dominated -= 1
                    if other_individual.dominated == 0:
                        other_individual.rank = i + 1
                        next_front.append(other_individual)
            i += 1
            fronts.append(next_front)
        if len(fronts[-1]) == 0:
            fronts.pop(-1)
        self.fronts = fronts


    #Function to perform the crowding distance assignment
    def crowding_distance_assignment(self, front):
        for individual in front:
            individual.crowding_distance = 0.0
        for i in range(len(self.objectives)):
            front.sort(key = lambda x: x.objective_values[i])
            front[0].crowding_distance = float('inf')
            front[-1].crowding_distance = float('inf')
            for j in range(1, len(front) - 1):
                front[j].crowding_distance += (front[j + 1].objective_values[i] - front[j - 1].objective_values[i]) / (front[-1].objective_values[i] - front[0].objective_values[i] + 1e-6)

    
    #Function to perform the crowding distance sorting
    def crowding_distance_sorting(self):
        for front in self.fronts:
            self.crowding_distance_assignment(front)
            front.sort(key = lambda x: x.crowding_distance, reverse = True)
    
    #Function to perform the NSGA-II algorithm
    def run(self):
        self.non_dominated_sorting()
        self.crowding_distance_sorting()

        while self.current_generation < self.generations:
            self.offspring_population = []
            for i in range(self.population_size//2):
                parent1 = self.tournament_selection()
                parent2 = self.tournament_selection()
                child1, child2 = self.crossover(parent1, parent2)
                self.mutation(child1)
                self.mutation(child2)
                self.offspring_population.append(child1)
                self.offspring_population.append(child2)

            
            self.population.extend(self.offspring_population)
            self.non_dominated_sorting()
            self.crowding_distance_sorting()
            self.population = []
            for front in self.fronts:
                if len(self.population) + len(front) <= self.population_size:
                    self.population.extend(front)
                else:
                    self.crowding_distance_assignment(front)
                    front.sort(key = lambda x: x.crowding_distance, reverse = True)
                    self.population.extend(front[:self.population_size - len(self.population)])
            self.current_generation += 1
        return self.fronts[0]

def generate_dtlz1_objectives(M, n):
    """
    Generates a list of DTLZ1 objective functions.
    
    Parameters:
    M (int): Number of objectives.
    n (int): Number of dimensions (variables).
    
    Returns:
    list: A list of lambda functions representing the DTLZ1 objective functions.
    """
    k = n - M + 1  # Number of variables involved in the g function

    def g(x):
        xM = np.array(x[-k:])
        return 100 * (k + np.sum((xM - 0.5)**2 - np.cos(20 * np.pi * (xM - 0.5))))

    objectives = []
    for i in range(1, M + 1):
        if i == 1:
            # For the first objective, use all except the last element
            objectives.append(lambda x: 0.5 * np.prod(np.array(x)[:M-1]) * (1 + g(x)))
        elif i < M:
            # For middle objectives, exclude progressively more elements
            objectives.append(lambda x, i=i: 0.5 * np.prod(np.array(x)[:M-i]) * (1 - x[M-i]) * (1 + g(x)))
        else:
            # For the last objective, use the negation of the first element
            objectives.append(lambda x, i=i: 0.5 * (1 - x[0]) * (1 + g(x)))

    return objectives

def run1():
    # Example of using the NSGA-II algorithm
    population_size = 100
    generations = 300
    dimensions = 7 
    mutation_rate = 1/dimensions
    crossover_rate = 1
    tournament_size = 2
    M = 3  # Number of objectives
    objectives = generate_dtlz1_objectives(M, dimensions)

    #Example of using the NSGA-II algorithm
    bounds = [(0, 1) for _ in range(dimensions)]
    nsga = NSGAII(population_size, generations, mutation_rate, crossover_rate, objectives, bounds, tournament_size, dimensions)
    front = nsga.run()
    print(front[0].values)
    #plot 3d 
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter([individual.objective_values[0] for individual in front], [individual.objective_values[1] for individual in front], [individual.objective_values[2] for individual in front])
    ax.set_xlabel('f1')
    ax.set_ylabel('f2')
    ax.set_zlabel('f3')
    plt.show()

run1()

